# Return multiple roles for user in 1 column not multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rows

SQL Server

I am trying to return 1 row for a user that contains their firstname, lastname, email etc and also all their roles contained in a separate roles table connected through UserRoles.

```
User              ->     UserRoles         ->    Role
-------------            ---------------         ------------
Email                    UserEmail               Id
Firstname                RoleId                  Name
Lastname
Phone
IsActive
```

```
  declare @Email nvarchar(100);
  set @Email = 'testemail@gmail.com'
  
  SELECT [User].Email, Password, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Phone, IsActive, EmailVerified, IsBanned, BanStart, BanEnd, [Role].Name as Roles
  FROM dbo.[User], [UserRole], [Role] 
  WHERE [User].Email = @Email AND UserRole.UserEmail = [User].Email AND UserRole.RoleId = Role.Id
```

Return

```
Email               Username            Firstname Lastname Phone IsActive EmailVerified IsBanned BanStart BanEnd Roles     
testemail@gmail.com testemail@gmail.com daniel  brownn  3199999999  1   0   0   NULL    NULL    Expert
testemail@gmail.com testemail@gmail.com daniel  brownn  3199999999  1   0   0   NULL    NULL    User
```

This returns the correct info unfortunately for a user with 2 roles it returns 2 separate rows. I aim to have 1 row returned with a comma separated value in the Roles column containing both the roles values. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh I have edited my question to show table structure sample and result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `JOIN` clause and `STRING_AGG` method. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you can find documentation of this method.
Your query result like this:

```sql
SELECT
  [User].Email,
  Password,
  Username,
  Firstname,
  Lastname,
  Phone,
  IsActive,
  EmailVerified,
  IsBanned,
  BanStart,
  BanEnd,
  STRING_AGG([Role].Name, ', ') as Roles
FROM
  dbo.[User]
  JOIN [UserRole] ON [UserRole].UserEmail = [User].Email
  LEFT JOIN [Role] ON [Role].Id = [UserRole].RoleId
GROUP BY
  [User].Email,
  Password,
  Username,
  Firstname,
  Lastname,
  Phone,
  IsActive,
  EmailVerified,
  IsBanned,
  BanStart,
  BanEnd
```

Note that `STRING_AGG` is a t-sql method, but there is something equivalent in MySQL (if I'm not wrong is `GOUP_CONCAT` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/) you can find something)